# Excel closest match with index/match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question regarding the closest match when using index/match formula.
I use CONCAT to make a new field out of 3 cells. In the last cell I have a number, varying from 0 to 10.

So I get fields like ABCCBD3,ABCCBD5, ABCCBD7, ABCCBD10 etc.
I need to find closes matches for 5 and 10 in the end.

For example, if my INDEX/MATCH lookup finds ABCCBD6 (any number above 5 in the end) it should identify it as ABCCB10. If it finds from ABCCBD to ABCCBD5 it should identify it as ABCCBD5.

Because in my lookup I need to fill columns either "5" or "10". So any result from ABCCBD to ABCCBD5 will go to column named "5" while any result from ABCCBD6 to ABCCBD10 will go to "10" column. Is this something doable?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a visual representation of what it is you are after?

Comment: Just updated my question with a visual sample.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

[image]

Formula in `G4`, if one has O365:

```
=LET(X,FILTER($D4:$E9,CEILING($D4:$D9,5)=G3),INDEX(X,0,1)&INDEX(X,0,2))
```

Drag right.

With earlier versions of Excel, try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$9,SMALL(IF(CEILING($D$4:$D$9,5)=G$3,ROW(D$4:D$9),""),ROW(A1)))&INDEX($E$1:$E$9,SMALL(IF(CEILING($D$4:$D$9,5)=G$3,ROW(D$4:D$9),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

It's an CSE-entered formula. Drag right and down.

Comment: Can not use FILTER. Is there any other way?